# Bootstrap Collapse Is Not Animated The First Time And Has a Jittery Animation After The First Time

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so the bootstrap collapse is simply animation less when it collapses for the first time, it's just as if i used javascript to change the display from none to block with no animations, however when the collapsible element is getting hidden there is no jittering and is everything is normal to my surprise, but after that whenever you collapse the element again it is jittery.

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fyuskf9v/

and the html since most issues involving jittery collapses were caused by the html (others included paddings as well, but i have no padding on my elements):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%;">
<a href="#social" class="btn" id="socialToggle" data-toggle="collapse">Social Media <span id="bottomChevron" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:90%;"></span></a>

    <div class="container collapse" id="social">

    <div class="col-md-12">

    <ul id="socialList">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook-f"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-github-alt"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

see the fiddle for the css.

the first bug (first click animationlessness) is fixed when i remove "height:33%" on #social, and the second bug (jittery when becomes visible) is fixed when i remove "height:100%" on the ".col-md-12" (direct child of the last element).

please provide me with any links concerning bootstrap collapse bugs caused by heights.

Comment: It's definitely something in the style sheet.  I deleted it on the fiddle and the jittery behavior goes away.  I would suggest process of elimination.

Comment: just found out it is with these two:


#social {
width:100%;
height:33%; 
padding:0
}

#social .col-md-12 {
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0;
}

Comment: Glad you found it.  Interesting bug with Bootstrap. Maybe it's the 33% height... redrawing the container on each tween and computing the % could be the issue.

Comment: the second jitters are fixed when i delete the "height:100%" for the .col-md-12 element, and the first animation-lessness  is fixed when i delete "height:33%", i haven't found anything on element height's causing anything with collapses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my second comment indicates, it's the percentages on the heights.  This works:

```
#social {
width:100%;
xxheight:100px; 
padding:0
}

#social .col-md-12 {
width:100%;
height:300px;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: so there are no workarounds ? or how do i make this responsive?

Comment: There may be a work around... experimentation is the only way to know. How responsive does it need to be?

Comment: well that's responsive enough, but with your code, it's jittery when it's getting hidden, and if i play with these height values the bug is never fixed, only changes from occuring when it's getting hidden to occuring when it's shown the first time.

Comment: hm - it wasn't jittery for me at all on Chrome.  Interesting.

Comment: I went back and played a bit more, the height on #social is not needed.  See if you get jitters with just the height on #social .col-md-12